# Which Magic cards have format-specific errata?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[The Scryfall page for Chaos Orb](https://scryfall.com/card/2ed/236/chaos-orb) has a note:

> If you are playing Chaos Orb in the Old School format, the card's text is “{1}, {T}: Choose a nontoken permanent on the battlefield. If Chaos Orb is on the battlefield, flip Chaos Orb onto the battlefield from a height of at least one foot. If Chaos Orb turns over completely at least once during the flip, and lands resting on the chosen permanent, destroy that permanent. Then destroy Chaos Orb.”

I'm curious what other cards have errata specific to certain formats like this. Looking up the Old School format, I couldn't find anything about this modification to Chaos Orb.

Comment: "Old School" is an unofficial format, and it is not standardized. The errata may come from [this Hareruya article](https://article.hareruyamtg.com/article/article_en_316/?lang=en), which cites [this ChannelFireball article (archived)](https://article.hareruyamtg.com/article/article_en_316/?lang=en).

Answer (score 6):

##### No sanctioned formats contain format-specific errata.

A card has the same text in all official (paper) formats. Old School is an unofficial format who have chosen to let Chaos Orb (one of the very few cards on the Vintage ban list) to be played, but from reading the text, they have nerfed it somewhat so it can affect only one permanent. It is worth noting the text you have quoted is a "Scryfall note, 2019-01-27", not an official ruling from Wizards. I'm sure other unofficial formats contain specific tweaks as well.

##### What's with that "(paper)" qualifier?

Alchemy and Historic, the digital-only formats available in MtG: Arena, *do* have changes to cards for those formats only. For example, [Omnath, Locus of Creation](https://scryfall.com/card/znr/A-232/a-omnath-locus-of-creation) costs an additional mana in those formats as opposed to [paper formats](https://scryfall.com/card/znr/232/omnath-locus-of-creation). You can argue semantics about whether this is an errata, a "digital rebalancing", a nerf and whether the two cards are the same card or different cards.

Comment: The Arena format changes is a good example, although those changes can be much more than simple errata (they can change casting cost or power/toughness, add or remove entire abilities, etc.). If you want to search up these rebalanced versions, Scryfall differentiates them using a "A-" in front of their normal name, so "A-Orcish Bowmasters" is the nerfed version that removes the ETB trigger. Good luck trying to figure out *which* Arena formats support which version of each, however.

Comment: @bradC as far as I know all formats use the rebalanced (or in some cases like [Symmetry Sage](https://scryfall.com/card/stx/A-56/a-symmetry-sage) further unbalanced) versions of the cards. The only way you play the original printed versions were in direct one on one games where anything goes.

Comment: @Andrew Pretty sure Standard, (60-card) Brawl, and Explorer formats use the original versions; Alchemy, Historic, and (100-card) Historic Brawl use the rebalanced versions. But there have also been bugs in various formats where the wrong version was used. That's why I said "good luck", because even if you figure out how it is *supposed* to work, it hasn't always been implemented correctly.

Comment: What @BradC says - Standard _is_ the same as paper Standard, and Explorer is "paper Pioneer lite" so they both use the unmodified cards. 95% sure on 60-card Brawl as well. This is supported by the Omnath links in my answer - the unmodified card is legal in Pioneer, while the modified card is legal in Historic.

Comment: Not to mention special events using more specialized formats (singleton, pauper, etc.); sometimes they specify ("alchemy pauper", for example), other times you just have to see which versions of cards show up in the deck builder.